# can we get the onedrive uploaded file link after upload is completed?

Tags: c#, rest, onedrive

I am uploading the file to One drive using Rest Api c# successfully.My requirement is to get the uploaded file link and push that into database.when I Googled I cannot find any relevant information on that.kindly help me to solve this query

Answer (score 0):

Getting a download link is documented here: Downloading and Uploading files (REST) (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659726.aspx). At the bottom, it states "To get a download link to the contents of a file, photo, video, or audio, use code like this.

GET https://apis.live.net/v5.0/file.a6b2a7e8f2515e5e.A6B2A7E8F2515E5E!126/content?suppress_redirects=true?
    access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
"
I hope this helps.

Comment: "suppress redirect" is not working, I have tested it many times in last couple of days.

I need to get download URL of the file using OneDrive API. This works string url = "https://apis.live.net/v5.0/" + FILE_ID + "/shared_read_link?access_token=" + AUTH_TOKEN

but this doesn't string url = "https://apis.live.net/v5.0/" + FILE_ID + "/content?suppress_redirects=true?access_token=" + AUTH_TOKEN;

Its throwing error, unauthorized.. can someone tell why?

Thanks. Sujit

Comment: & should have been used in place of ?. So correct answer is

string url = "https://apis.live.net/v5.0/" + FILE_ID + "/content?suppress_redirects=true&access_token=" + AUTH_TOKEN;